# Django - how to use HttpBasicAuth

Tags: django

In my Django code I am writing  a `connection.py`, which will connect to another server using the following `http_auth = http_auth.HTTPBasicAuth(user password)`. So when I am connecting to that server one of the parameter I pass is `http_auth = http_auth.HTTPBasicAuth(user password)` against the server. I searched the web a lot and Django docs but nothing exactly tells me how to do this? Can anyone please help

Comment: Please post the relevant parts of `connection.py`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of how you might use Django's Basic Authentication when presenting Users as RESTful resources:

```
# REST endpoint for authenticating user accounts
class UserResource(ModelResource):

    class Meta:
        queryset = User.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'auth/user'
        authentication = BasicAuthentication()
        authorization = DjangoAuthorization()

    def apply_authorization_limits(self, request, object_list):
        return object_list.filter(username=request.user)
```

Authentication can be as simple as the one line:

```
        authentication = BasicAuthentication()
```

depending on how you implement it.